# How to build non-qt project in Qt Creator statically

Tags: c++, qt, static-linking

I have a Qt 5.5 dynamically linked installed with MingW 4.9.2 32-bit and Qt Creator 3.4.2. In my build tree I created a helper console non-Qt app that has literally 20 lines of code and does not rely on Qt (only uses qmake so I do not have to install cmake). I would like that app to be built statically but no option I set in the build make arguments seems to be accepted (static, static-libgcc etc.). Is it even possible or do I have to build it separately outside of Qt(Creator) and possibly get cmake instead of qmake?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question.

Your situation is: you are building an app that is not using Qt and you are using QMake. QtCreator can create new non-qt projects using qmake or cmake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wish to link the executable statically to the C++ runtime, then the `static_runtime` feature does it. You'll also want not to link with Qt:

```
# .pro file
CONFIG -= qt
CONFIG += static_runtime
```

The `static_runtime.prf` file is only available in Qt 5/6. It's not present in Qt 4. For Qt 4, you have to do it manually:

```
QMAKE_LFAGS += -static
```